# redirect if url doesn't match parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website incorrectly indexed on Google, like this:
www.mysite.fr/de-DE/mypage

I need to fix it, with a 301 redirect to www.mysite.de/de-DE/mypage
To put it simple, the first level domain (.it, .de, fr...) should correspond to the second url parameter (it-IT, de-DE, fr-FR...).
How can I do it using .htaccess only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%{HTTP_HOST} ^/([a-z]{2})-.*?::(?:www\.)?mysite\.\1$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.mysite.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: this will not be as easy for countries with multiple languages. For example, do you forward .ch to `de-CH` or to `fr-CH`?

Comment: Agreed for those it won't work as top level domain cannot be matched by first part of URI only

Comment: Well, at the moment it-IT, de-DE, fr-FR and es-ES are the only supported languages. I think this solution will solve my problem, at least for now... Thank you.